# Float two images

Tags: html, css

I've this code

```css
.container {
    background-color: #ececec;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
</div>
```

I want the first image to be at the left of the `.container` and the second one at the right.

Theses images have to be centered, and I don't wanna use flexblox (I heard about trouble of compatibility like IE)

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: do you use bootstrap?

Comment: You mean centered vertically?

Comment: OH God! Stop bringing up Bootstrap for everything!

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith it will good to know, if he want achieve it bu using bootstrap or not, beacuse class names and images are similar to bootstrap examples.

Comment: This is a SIMPLE fix in CSS only, why are we over complicating this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tables for that.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #ececec;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.img-container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.image2 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="img-container image2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why completely change the OP's HTML?

Comment: What is your problem with that? He did not mention that he has to use his markup to achieve his goal.

Comment: Its just excessive, is all.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/rfb31uto/

```
.container {   
    background-color: #ececec;
    width: 100%;
}
img{vertical-align: middle;}
img:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: calc(100% - 305px);
}
```